# Ubuntu nautilus window setting changed

Tags: nautilus

Any one help me with it please.
I can't reset to default setting.

[image: Nautilus screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've just accidentally expanded the sidebar.

Place the mouse pointer at the border between sidebar and tab, then click and drag to your left.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to drag it left but it's not dragging